# dynamic jquery smooth scoll

Tags: jquery, each

i'm trying to use the jquery smooth scroll, within an es6 class, but i'm having a bit of trouble implementing it. i have a nav menu that i just simply want to scroll to the specified location when clicked. i believe the issue is with my .each() loop but i'm not sure. it kind of works, it seems to be grabbing attributes i set, but only the first one and does not scroll. here is my code:

```
<nav class="primary-nav primary-nav--pull-right">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#github">Github</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

JS

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import smoothScroll from 'jquery-smooth-scroll';

class StickyHeader {

  constructor(){
    this.headerLinks = $("nav.primary-nav a");
    this.events();
    $.smoothScroll();
  }

  events() {
    var that = this;
    this.headerLinks.click(function() {
      var currentLink = that.headerLinks;
      currentLink.each(function() {    
      $.smoothScroll({
        scrollElement: currentLink,
        speed: 1000,
        offset: -100,
        scrollTarget: currentLink.attr('href')
      });
      console.log(that.headerLinks.attr('href'));
      return false;
      });
    });

  }
}

export default StickyHeader;
```